# JMeter failed url attempts followed by correct url for HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

How can I get JMeter to only attempt 1 url instead of 5 each time I run a test?

I am using a different site which is internal, but let's say I was using "blah.com" for the sake of discussion.

I see this in the View Results Tree:

```
http://blah.com
https://blah.com
https://blah.com/abc
http://blah.com/abc
https://blah.com/abc
```

In the same order, here are my http response codes:

- 301 Moved permenantly
- 301 Moved permenantly
- 302 Found
- 301 Moved permenantly
- 200 Ok

If I want Jmeter to just go straight to the 5th one so that I get the 200 code right away, what do I have to do  in JMeter settings?

I have:

- HTTP Cookie Manager
- HTTP Cache Manager
- HTTP Request ( with "blah.com" filled in for the server name )

under HTTP Request, I have all of these:

- HTTP Header Manager
- Response Assertion ( with some url patterns checking for html tags - I just copied the html from View Source and pasted it in as a url pattern...these all seem to work )
- Response Assertion ( just checking response code - I chose Response Code and entered "200"...this also seems to work )
- Summary Report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this down to 1.  Adjustments made to the HTTP Request:

I added "/abc" to "Path" and changed "Follow Redirects" to "Redirect Automatically".